# I can't understand this phrase, is this slang? 「デカくてトロくて」

Tags: translation, slang, idioms

> デカくてトロくて

This is from a manga I'm reading, and here is the whole sentence "デカくてトロくて使いやすいジャンプ台だった." For context purposes, this is a soccer manga and refers to a part where a forward was sure to be the one jumping highest, only to be surpassed by a defender, who is the one saying the phrase. This defender use the other player shoulder to jump higher. I have no idea what デカ and トロ mean here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of the two is slang, really.

「デカい」 is an informal word for 「[大]{おお}きい」.  It should be found in every dictionary.

「とろい」 is a regular dictionary word meaning "dull", "stupid", etc.  Perhaps the katakana part fooled you.  That is just to give the word a slangy look and feel.

「デカ**く**」 and 「トロ**く**」 are just the continuative forms of 「デカ**い**」 and 「トロ**い**」, respectively.  The sentence uses **three** adjectives in a row, thus the first two must be put in the continuative form.

> ***"It/He was a big, stupid and easy-to-use jump stand."***